# How can I obtain the default value for a type in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a wrapper that calls a method, and if an exception is thrown, logs it and returns a default value.

```
InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new InvocationHandler() {
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return invokeOn(wrapped, method, args);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Throwable targetException = e.getTargetException();
            if (targetException instanceof Exception) {
                errorReporter.exception(wrapped, (Exception) targetException);
                return defaultValueFor(method.getReturnType());
            } else {
                throw targetException;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I'd like to find a nice way of implementing defaultValueFor so that it returns a good default value for each possible type - the equivalent of

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected static <T> T defaultValueFor(Class<T> claz) {
    if (claz == boolean.class)
        return (T) Boolean.FALSE;
    if (claz == short.class)
        return (T) Short.valueOf((short) 0);
    if (claz == int.class)
        return (T) Integer.valueOf(0);
    if (claz == long.class)
        return (T) Long.valueOf(0);
    ...
    return null;
}
```

This sort of code must be in JMock etc, but is there a nicer implementation than this horrible boiler-plate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class DefaultValues {
    static final Map<Class<?>,Object> defaultValues = new HashMap<Class<?>,Object>();

    // load
    static {
        defaultValues.put(boolean.class, Boolean.FALSE);
        defaultValues.put(byte.class, new Byte((byte)0));
        defaultValues.put(short.class, new Short((short)0));
        defaultValues.put(int.class, new Integer(0));
        defaultValues.put(long.class, new Long(0L));
        defaultValues.put(char.class, new Character('\0'));
        defaultValues.put(float.class, new Float(0.0F));
        defaultValues.put(double.class, new Double(0.0));
    }

    public static final <T> T defaultValueFor(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T)defaultValues.get(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need clazz.cast(defaultValues.get(clazz)) in there?

Comment: I suppose that there are only entries for boolean, char, short, byte, int, long, float and double, after which I can return null, but I was still hoping for something even more elegant ;-)

Comment: @Duncan because the default value will be null for all Objects, and those objects won't be in the array, you won't have to special case it. It will be null by virtue of not being in the map.

Comment: Indeed. I hope you don't mind, as I was implementing your suggestion (until something nicer comes along ;-) I've edited your post to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @Duncan of course I don't. Although I removed `void` since there's no point in putting a null entry in. :-)

Comment: Interesting - I'd left it in so that I didn't forget it next time I cut and paste that list of types!

Comment: @Duncan - you actually can forget it though :-) by virtue of simply not being in the map, it's default value is null.

Comment: Here yes, but not when I need a list of all the primitive return types to a method. I guess my coding has become more defensive as I'm getting older. I'd rather put it in the list than have to think through why it doesn't need to be there next time I read the code.